# Replacement of old c in c++

Tags: c++, c, replace

Here is the simple old C codes :

```
typedef struct {
    double EditionDate;
    double epoch;
    char ModelName[32];
    double *Main_Field_Coeff_G;
    double *Main_Field_Coeff_H;
    double *Secular_Var_Coeff_G;
    double *Secular_Var_Coeff_H;
    int nMax;
    int nMaxSecVar;
    int SecularVariationUsed;
    double CoefficientFileEndDate; 

} MAGtype_MagneticModel;

MAGtype_MagneticModel *TimedMagneticModel, *MagneticModels[1];

if(!MAG_robustReadMagModels(filename, &MagneticModels, epochs)) {
        printf("\n WMM.COF not found.  Press enter to exit... \n ");
    fgets(ans, 20, stdin);
    return 1;
}
```

And here is the error in c++ :

```
    131 IntelliSense: argument of type "MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[1]" is
incompatible with parameter of type "MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]"

error C2664: 'int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *,MAGtype_MagneticModel
*(*)[],int)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[1]' 
to 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]'
```

How can i fix this error in c# ?

Comment: _"How can i fix this error in c# ?"_ Huh??

Comment: MAGtype_MagneticModel *TimedMagneticModel, `(*MagneticModels)`[1];

Comment: An array of one pointer is not a particularly sensible type — in C or C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler GMP uses one-element array typedefs to have variables that are implicitly passed by address -- Maybe something similar is happening here ?

Comment: Also, since you've not shown us the declaration of `MAG_robustReadMagModels()`, it is hard to know what's required.  Either the call is erroneous (you probably don't want the `&`) or the function declaration is problematic.

Comment: @Quentin: It may be something like that — I think we need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get that you got C code which you're compiling in C++ and yet want to fix it's errors in C# , why? Oo. Anyways Function declaration is  -> `int MAG_robustReadMagModels(char *, MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[] ,int)` and second parameter is  :

`MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[]` -> you can either declare the array bound i.e `MAGtype_MagneticModel *(*)[1]` , since array bound has to be filled in case of one dimensional array.

or

change the declaration of second parameter to -> `MAGtype_MagneticModel **` and simply call function as `MAG_robustReadMagModels(filename, MagneticModels, epochs)`